SDDM PreSession
Need to run the script in SDDM after initializing the user session with sudo rights and use the $USER variable of the logged-in user in it.
GDM has PreSession and PostLogin
https://www.jirka.org/gdm-documentation/x220.html
SDDM has Xsetup - run as root before the login dialog appears
But the $USER variable in this case shows root
SDDM Xsession correctly identifies the user, but requires a password to execute commands with sudo
I don't want to add an executable script to sudoers
How can do this in SDDM?
